# Ionic/Firebase store data local and sync

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, firebase, local-storage, angularfire

I am not able figure out how i am going to store data locally and sycn with firebase so user can have data if he restart the app or even the internet is available or not.

Comment: This question is too broad for this community. Firebase has proper documentation to handle this kind of situations. You might take a look again.

Comment: thx but no thx as i already know the any from the post and actually want to know if some one does any job on that.